# PdfTron Webviewer is not working in Xamarin Hybrid app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, hybrid-mobile-app, pdftron

We are working on Xamarin mobile application (hybrid). We are using PdfTron for converting files(pdf/txt) to xod files using web application (Asp.Net) and displaying xod file in pdftron webviwer. In asp.net application everything is working fine.

In Android app we are able to render xod file in pdftron webviewer but webviewer overlap application content so we are not able to see controls of our application after render pdftron webviewer. Please find the attached screenshots. First screenshot display the menu bar [image] and second screenshot (after rendering pdftron) overlap the menu bar [image].

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve problem by setting "mobileRedirect: false". Below is code:

```
 var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer(
                        {
                            path: "file:///android_asset/lib",
                            type: "html5",
                            mobileRedirect: false,
                            initialDoc: "file:///android_asset/635979952755439967_articles.xod"
                        },
                        viewerElement);
```

and in mainactivity.cs file:

```
if (url.Contains("MobileReaderControl.html"))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
else
{
     webView.LoadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for following up! WebViewer comes with two ReaderControls, one for desktop, and a Mobile version for tablets/phones. From the API documentation "a boolean indicating whether the mobile viewer should redirect to a new window or not (mobile only, default true)". https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/doc/symbols/PDFTron.WebViewer.Options.html